# Multibyte character error in Oracle while trying to load block elements

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

We have flat file which we are trying to load into an Oracle 19c table using SQL*Loader, but it fails with "Multibyte character error" for one of the CHAR(2) field. We know it's a junk value but still we have to load it into the database. The database character set is AL32UTF8.

The value we are trying to load is a block element : [U+2592    ▒   Medium shade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Block_Elements)

We tried using UTF-8 in the SQL*Loader control file but are still facing the same issue. Any advice how to proceed?

Command:

```
sqlldr $connection parfile=SCHEMA.TABLE.par
```

Error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table SCHEMA.TABLE, column COL2.
Multibyte character error.

COLUMN info :COL2 CHAR(2) NOT NULL ENABLE
```

Parameter file contents:

```
data=filename.dat
control=SCHEMA.TABLE.ctl
log=SCHEMA.TABLE.log
bad=SCHEMA.TABLE.bad
```

Control file contents:

```
OPTIONS (BINDSIZE=20000000,READSIZE=10485760,ROWS=10000,DIRECT=FALSE,ERRORS=50)
        LOAD DATA
        CHARACTERSET 'AL32UTF8'
        DISCARDMAX 100
        REPLACE PRESERVE BLANKS INTO TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE
        TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COL1    POSITION(1:15) "NVL(:COL1,' ')",
COL2    POSITION(16:17) "NVL(:COL2,' ')"
)
```

File characterset:

```
filename.dat: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

OS: GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-3DB632A7-BF43-40EF-AB2C-A1CC095854C2):

> The start and end arguments to the `POSITION` parameter are interpreted in bytes, even if character-length semantics are in use in a data file.

So `POSITION(16:17)` is the 16th and 17th *bytes* of the line, not 16th (and only, in your example) character. The U+2592 character  [is three bytes in UTF-8](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2592/index.htm) - `0xE2 0x96 0x92 (e29692)` - and you're only looking at the first two bytes; and those on their own don't represent a valid character.

You can change from using `POSITION` to using `CHAR` with the fixed length of each field, and specify `LENGTH SEMANTICS CHARACTER`:

```
OPTIONS (BINDSIZE=20000000,READSIZE=10485760,ROWS=10000,DIRECT=FALSE,ERRORS=50)
        LOAD DATA
        CHARACTERSET 'AL32UTF8'
        LENGTH SEMANTICS CHARACTER
        DISCARDMAX 100
        REPLACE PRESERVE BLANKS INTO TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE
        TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COL1    CHAR(15) "NVL(:COL1,' ')",
COL2    CHAR(2) "NVL(:COL2,' ')"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has worked in case of the test table i have mentioned above. What if the table has Char,varchar2,number,data columns as well. It is giving Syntax error with "LENGTH SEMANTICS CHARACTER"

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question, including your current control file, table DDL, sample data file and the full error you get.